# Export and split QUERY results in multiple files

Tags: sql-server, export, csv, files, split

I would like to know if it's possible to export and split query results in multiple files. Let's assume I have a query returning 100 results and I want to save the results in 5 different csv files (20 results per file). Is there any way to do it?

Regards,

Comment: your best bet is to use powershell. This way you can chunk your result into different files.